# Windows 8.1 installation from USB after deleting Windows Boot Manager in BIOS/UEFI

Tags: bios, uefi, bootable-media, gpt, boot-manager

I removed ***Windows Boot Manager*** option from BIOS (UEFI) with [EasyUEFI](http://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html), after reboot I got an error message about broken BCD, need to be recovered, I tried to reinstall Windows 8.1.1 Pro X64 from USB installation, which I prepared with [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie/), there I set ***GPT partition scheme for UEFI computer***, but when I tried to boot from this USB and perform installation I get the message ***Operation System not found***.

I played with boot settings in BIOS, tried all possible boot combinations: legacy, Secure Boot On/Off, BIOS/UEFI, but I still can't make my Windows USB Boot stick work.

The only I can do is to install Ubuntu/Xubuntu on my laptop, but I need Windows. I also tried to completely rebuild disk partitions during Xubuntu 14.04 installation and after that retry to install Windows, but it doesn't work too.

I paid attention, that before I deleted ***Windows Boot Manager*** I could add Windows 8.1.1 boot option from USB in BIOS/UEFI, but now there is no such option, it only let choose SATA and not USB.

How to install Windows after I removed ***Windows Boot Manager*** from the BIOS boot tab?

I'm using Dell Vostro 3460 laptop, with the latest system BIOS v.A19.

Thanks!

Comment: Legacy and secureboot off should allow it.  If thats not working theres something with your USB key. Try Unetbootin instead of rufus, or another tool.

Comment: Just a nit: the firmware in your computer is either BIOS or UEFI. These are _alternatives_ to each other. UEFI is not a type of BIOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in that I formatted installation USB-stick into NTFS file system instead of FAT32. Now, when I rebuilt installation media with Rufus everything is working!

Thanks.